# How to stop twenty fifteen theme from cropping featured images?

Tags: functions, themes, post-thumbnails, theme-twenty-fifteen

The twenty fifteen theme always crops featured images, it cuts from both lower and upper part of the image usually.

How to prevent it? How to show the normal (full) dimensions of featured images?

In functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 825, 510, true );
```

changing above to higher dimensions dont take any effect.
How to fix?

Comment: Have you found a solution to avoid cropping completely for the featured image?

Answer (score 0):

if you already uploaded the image, and change the resolution, it will not affected, unless you regenerate the thumbnail or upload a new one.

Comment: how can I do that to all of previously uploaded images? Their upper and lower parts cropped in twenty fifteen theme.

Comment: I usually use plugin regenerate thumbnail to do that.